# Unable to run file using Schtasks , in win 7

Tags: windows-xp, cmd, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

Using Schtasks command i create a job.

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 20 /tn "My App" /tr c:\run.bat
```

it created successfully and run also.

Inside the run.bat file file i write this code :

```
dir > sctask.txt
```

When i double click on run.bat file it create the sctask.txt file and all dir name of that folder into sctask.txt.

But when run.bat file excuted by Schtasks  it is not create sctask.txt but it run the run.bat file

Answer (score 0):

Probably `schtasks` runs bat file from other directory. Try to add `cd "%~dp0"` to the start of the file.